# Google Sheets: How to create a nested IF statement with MATCH function?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, nested

I have been looking for a solution to this for quite a few hours, but unfortunately I appear to be stuck. I am trying to automatically input data based on another sheet with three possible options. `DEADLINE`, `PMC` or `FMC`, but it keeps crashing with if it can't find the first result. It will say `#N/A`, and tells me it can't find the first value. Why doesn't it check for the other values?

```
=IFS((MATCH(J8,Faults!F3:F9,0)),"DEADLINE",(MATCH(J6,Faults!F3:F9,0)),"PMC",(MATCH(J4,Faults!F3:F9,0)),"FMC")
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Better put some of your sample data and expected output. There may many solution with combination of other formulas.

Answer (score 0):

MATCH does not return TRUE or FALSE. It either returns a number (the position within the range) or a #N/A error.

IFS will throw an error and stop processing just as a nested IF will. Wrap all the match functions in ISNUMBER to bypass thrown #N/A errors on no match.

```
=IFS(isnumber(MATCH(J8, Faults!F3:F9, 0)),"DEADLINE", isnumber(MATCH(J6, Faults!F3:F9, 0)), "PMC", isnumber(MATCH(J4, Faults!F3:F9, 0)), "FMC", true, "other")
```

I've added a default of *Other* if none of the three matches are found.